# Running Yocto in Docker, "make menuconfig" fails

Tags: docker, embedded, yocto, bitbake

Running Yocto in a Docker container, I can't execute "make menuconfig"

```
$ MACHINE=varsomam33 bitbake -c menuconfig linux-ti-variscite

ERROR: No valid terminal found, unable to open devshell
ERROR: Function failed: do_menuconfig
```

Comment: I think installing `tmux` could solve this problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
    Solution: gnu "screen" command

    Bitbake tries to spawn a number of terminal programs, most of which fail
    because A) they're not installed or B) they require X Windows.  We can't
    execute X terminals in the docker command-line (no X support).

    So the most viable terminal is gnu screen.

    In my ubuntu docker container:
        $ sudo apt-get install screen
        $ tty             // Shows "not a tty", we're trying to fix that

    Get in the docker containter as root  (something like:   docker exec -it $(docker ps -q) /bin/bash )
        # agetty tty        // This will present you with a login prompt, login as your regular yocto user
        $ tty               // Should show a valid tty
        $ screen            // Start a screen session
        $ cd build          // Got to Yocto build dir
        $ source conf/setenv
        $ MACHINE=varsomam33 bitbake -c menuconfig linux-ti-variscite    // Will spawn a new "screen" terminal, using ncurses for menuconfig
```

Comment: `screen` is yocto's least favorite option to spawn the developer shell and in our case results in a tiny menuconfig screen. `tmux` works much better for us.

Comment: i am getting this error : export: `affinity:container==afb2619bde7c0843608af0008ad36bb6128599b94038a1be4b16b1d4e1726edd': not a valid identifier in run.do_teminal task in yocto

Answer (score 4):

We use the same setup (yocto in a docker container), but `tty` does show a valid tty (maybe because we use `--tty` with `docker exec`?).

We are still missing a terminal emulator in our image, though. When using newer versions of yocto, you will be provided with a list of commands yocto tried to spawn the development shell, like this:

```
ERROR: busybox-1.24.1-r0 do_menuconfig: No valid terminal found, unable to open devshell.
Tried the following commands:
    tmux split-window "do_terminal"
    [...]
    screen -D -m -t "busybox Configuration" -S devshell do_terminal
```

When using older versions of yocto, you might want to apply the [commit](http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/?id=93e8db222444a7aac24c5153d187bf23613c1768) implementing the output of the list of tried commands.

The solution is now obvious: Install a (non-windowed) terminal emulator, e.g., tmux (`apt-get install tmux`).

Answer (score 2):

Brad's answer is correct (rep too low to even +1 or comment back)

I have a Docker image (Dockerfile includes FROM ubuntu:trusty and created a builduser account) and did the following:

From my local PC terminal #1 :

```
// my Dockerfile will default into USER builduser account, use 'sudo' if you need to here
$ docker run -it <my image name from 'docker images'> /bin/bash
$ tty
/dev/console
```

With the image loaded into a container, I'll open another PC terminal #2 and execute Brad's suggestion of installing 'screen' as root (root password is disabled by default on Ubuntu images, so this is a workaround):

```
// -u parameter is <user id> and root's uid is 0
$ docker exec -u 0 -it <my temporary container id from 'docker ps -q'> /bin/bash
// notice command prompt went to '#' indicating root
# apt-get install screen
# tty
not a tty
```

Going back to PC terminal #1, start your build within a 'screen' session:

```
$ which screen
/usr/bin/screen
$ tty
/dev/console
// start 'screen' session, will launch /bin/sh by default
$ screen
$ cd <build directory>   # your Yocto build dir
$ source <config file>   # (optional) your Yocto build env config file>
// will launch ncurses menuconfig after a build
$ MACHINE=varsomam33 bitbake -c menuconfig linux-ti-variscite
```

Answer (score 1):

`apt-get install screen` if the docker container is debian or ubuntu.